# Picasso does not load images over mobile network?

Tags: android, picasso

I am using picasso library for loading images from internet. While I am using wifi there is no trouble with picasso and all images loading finely. But when I use mobile network (like 3G, LTE) picasso does not load images, and only shows placeholder. How can I solve this problem ?

My Logcat with using Mobile Network;

```
03-24 01:29:41.671 2568-3227/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'INTERFACE' not found
03-24 01:29:41.671 2568-3227/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found
03-24 01:29:41.671 3189-3273/? E/NetdConnector: Error handling '613 IfaceClass idle (null)': java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "(null)"
03-24 01:29:47.801 3189-3530/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 5480
03-24 01:29:47.886 3189-3343/? E/ConnectivityService: updateNetworkInfo()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awxtG.png)

Comment: may be due to your poor internet connection ...please try to use Glide  https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html or post the error log here

Comment: I tried also Glide, same problem occurred with 3 different android devices has good internet connection. Thanks for your comment.